# How to connect to JDBC connecting string of local.settings.json?

Tags: java, azure-functions

I would like to write to SQL database by Java based Azure Functions.

I have SQLconnstring of JDBC in local.settings.json. How to get this connection correctly from settings file instead of hard coding to java file?

```
package com.function;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
/**
 * Azure Functions with Azure Storage Queue trigger.
 */
public class TopicTriggerSQLOutput {
    /**
     * This function will be invoked when a new message is received at the specified path. The 
message contents are provided as input to this function.
     */
    @FunctionName("TopicTriggerSQLOutput")
    public void run(
        @ServiceBusTopicTrigger(
            name = "message",
            topicName = "newtopic",
            subscriptionName = "newsubscription",
            connection = "topicconnstring"
        ) String message,
       final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        /*Creating SQL Connection. I need help here:
        */

            /*How to get connection string from local.settings.json instead of hard coding?*/
            String connectionUrl =
                    "jdbc:sqlserver://yourserver.database.windows.net:1433;"
                            + "database=AdventureWorks;"
                            + "user=yourusername@yourserver;"
                            + "password=yourpassword;"
                            + "encrypt=true;"
                            + "trustServerCertificate=false;"
                            + "loginTimeout=30;";

            try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);) {
                // SQL Code here.
            }
            // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        //context.getLogger().info(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.getenv("")` to get the value from `local.settings.json` file. For example, we can use `String connectionUrl =System.getenv("SQLConnectionString");` to get the sql connection string in the local.settings.json file.

[image]